# Web Programming with AJAX, Problem with caching (I think)

Tags: ajax

Web programmer here - using AJAX (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, AJAX, PHP, MySQL), but for some reason Internet Explorer is acting up (surprise surprise).

AJAX is updating query results on the HTML page, via a PHP script that queries a MySQL Database.

Everything is working fine, except when I use Internet Explorer 8.0 .

There are several php scripts, which allow for the data to be ordered according to certain criteria, and for testing purposes I have attached the mktime field (current time, in the format HH:MM:SS) to the beginning of the results for each query.
When I use IE, these times appear to remain constant, whereas with ALL other browsers these times are correct and display the current time.

I think the issue has something to do with caching or something along those lines anyway.

Any thoughts or suggestions welcome...

Comment: Nice work mate, Cant believe it was that simple!

Comment: I had an absolute headache with the same thing not too long ago so made a point of always remembering it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-ie-caching-issue) is an article on the caching issue.

If your request is a GET change it to a POST, this will prevent the results being cached.

Comment: Updated post with article link. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

GET requests are cached in IE; switch it to a POST request and it won't be cached anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switching to POST, which can be ugly if you're not really using it to update or create content, you should append a random number to the query string, as in `http://domain.com/ajax/some-request?r=123456`. If this number is unique for every request you won't have caching problems.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is, I have kept the "GET" and added new dummy query parameter to the querystring as follows,

```
./BaseServlet?sname=3d_motor&calcdir=20110514&dummyParam=datetime
```

I set *dummyParam* a value of date object in the javascript so that every time the url is generated browser will treat it as a new url and fetch new (fresh) results.

```
var d = new Date();
url = url + '&dummyParam='+d.valueOf();
```

So instead of generating some random numbers this is easy way!